# Bitbucket pipelines configuration file error

Tags: heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm new to bitbucket pipelines and I'm following this tutorial to deploy a react app to heroku.

[Deploy Reactjs app to Heroku with Multi-Environment Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/deploy-reactjs-app-to-heroku-with-multi-environment-bitbucket-ci-cd-pipeline-98bc4bf0672f)

However the file `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` seems to be incorrect.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong, and kindly help me to correct it?

Many thanks.

```
image: node:14.18.0

pipelines:
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
        name: Create artifacts
        script:
          - git archive --format=tar.gz main -o application.tar.gz
        artifacts:
          - application.tar.gz
      - step:
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: main
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.2.1
            variables:
              HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
              ZIP_FILE: application.tar.gz
    develop:
      - step:
        name: Create artifacts
        script:
          - git archive --format=tar.gz main -o application.tar.gz
        artifacts:
          - application.tar.gz
      - step:
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: main
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.2.1
            variables:
              HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
              ZIP_FILE: application.tar.gz
    default:
```

PS: A screenshot showing the errors that VSCode points out

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the indentation and BitBucket pipelines are sensitive on that.
[image]

In the left is correct formatted pipeline and in the right is what you are currently using.

Please also see bellow fully formatted pipeline

```
image: node:14.18.0

pipelines:
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          name: Create artifacts
          script:
          - git archive --format=tar.gz main -o application.tar.gz
          artifacts:
          - application.tar.gz
      - step:
          name: Deploy to production
          deployment: main
          caches:
          - node
          script:
          - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.2.1
            variables:
              HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
              ZIP_FILE: application.tar.gz
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Create artifacts
          script:
          - git archive --format=tar.gz main -o application.tar.gz
          artifacts:
          - application.tar.gz
      - step:
          name: Deploy to production
          deployment: main
          caches:
          - node
          script:
          - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.2.1
            variables:
              HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
              ZIP_FILE: application.tar.gz
```

Comment: I didn't know that it would be so sensitive to indentation. Your comment solved my problem. Many thanks.